# How can I see my hash rate?

Tags: monerod, cpu-mining, hashrate, monerod-commands

I am solo mining using monerod.  When I run './monerod show_hr', I am told 'Hash Rate Logging is on', but I can't find the files.  Where are they stored in Ubuntu 14.04?

Also, is it possible to redirect the output of this command to the display rather than a file so I can monitor the rate on a real-time basis?

Answer (score 5):

The log file is ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log. On Windows, it is somewhere else which someone who knows will edit here soon.

The `status` command reports your hash rate. If you're running a detached monerod:

`./monerod status`

You could use `watch` to run this at whatever interval you want, eg:

`watch -n 60 monerod status >> /tmp/monerod.log`

<s>Or you could grep the log, where the hash rate goes once requested by the `show_hr` command you included:</s>

`tail -f ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log | grep --line-buffered hashrate:`

Edit: The hashrate isn't logged, as mentioned below. Another way, then:

`(watch -t -n 60 './monerod status >> /tmp/monerod.log'&) 2>&1 2> /dev/null; tail -f /tmp/monerod.log`

Comment: Not having much luck, sorry. I want to display a continuous hash rate on the terminal. I expect that the tail command you suggested will do that, but, when I run it, I get nothing, only a flashing cursor at the start of a blank line. Running the status command shows that I am mining and gives me the hash rate. But, when I check the bitmonero.log I see only error messages, no hash rates. A typical entry is: 2017-08-16 19:12:31.287 7f2011a7c780 INFO global contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145 New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO Sor

Comment: Indeed, the hash rate isn't actually logged, you're right. I edited my answer with another command.

Answer (score 0):

"...so I can monitor the rate on a real-time basis?",
"I want to display a continuous hash rate on the terminal."

you can do that if you run monerod interactive (no "--detach") and type command:

```
show_hr
```

But it's maybe a good idea to start monerod inside a "screen"-session, so you can switch it to background and log off the machine. Otherwise you have to keep the terminal open all the time.
https://packages.debian.org/stretch/screen

```
screen
monerod
```

... do whaterver interactively in monerod. Inside screen Ctrl-a  "d" detaches session to backround.
To get it back use:

```
screen -r 
    # or if you have more than one screen
screen -r PID
```